# Append multiple Counter() objects and convert to Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-frequency

I would like to find word frequencies of a list of reserved words in multiple .txt files as a pandas data frame. I am using collections.Counter() objects and if a certain word does not appear in a text, the value of that word (key) is zero in the Counter().

Ideally, the result is a data frame where each row corresponds to each .txt file, column headers correspond to the reserved words and the entry in the row i column j corresponds to the frequency of j-th word in the i-th .txt file.

Here is my code, but the problem is that the Counter() objects are not appended, in the sense of a dictionary with multiple values for each key (or reserved word), but summed instead:

```
for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        cnt = Counter()
        tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', file.read().lower())
        for word in tokens:
            if word in mylist:
                cnt[word] += 1
            for key in mylist:
                if key not in cnt:
                    cnt[key] = 0
        dictionary = defaultdict(list)
        for key, value in cnt.items():
            dictionary[key].append(value)
    print(dictionary)
```

Any hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: You are using `Counter` wrong.  You are using it as it would be just a `defaultdict(int)`.  And setting keys to 0 isn't necessary because that's the value you get for a non-existing key anyway.  Also `dictionary` is created for each file and the value for the previous loop iteration is discarded.  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the dictionary for the dataframe before the loop and then copy/append the `Counter` values of each text file over.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob


def main():
    folder_path = '...'
    keywords = ['spam', 'ham', 'parrot']

    keyword2counts = {keyword: list() for keyword in keywords}
    for filename in iglob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
        with open(filename) as file:
            words = re.findall(r'\w+', file.read().lower())

        keyword2count = Counter(word for word in words if word in keywords)

        for keyword in keywords:
            keyword2counts[keyword].append(keyword2count[keyword])

    print(keyword2counts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Testing if for item in a `list` can be significantly slower than doing the same test for items in a `set`.  So if this is too slow you might use a `set` for `keywords` or an additional one just for the test.

And a `collections.OrderedDict` prior to Python 3.7 (or CPython 3.6) if the order of the columns is relevant.